# Redux actions callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am stuck in a situation wherein I call a redux action which updates state in store which in turn updates one component. I want to receive a callback when that component is updated. How can I receive that callback ?

Comment: receive a call back to where..! componentDidupdate would help you. But without code.. you get no chocolates!

Comment: Same place where I am calling the action. Its like the callback when that action is executed and corresponding components are updated

Comment: Why do you want that callback? Is this something the store change could accommodate instead of relying on a specific callback?

Comment: It is not something you should do but if you used react-redux connect then you could do `theAction(argument).then(()=>acion done here)` Assuming that theAction dispatches an action that is a function that returns a promise. I don't think you should ever use it, I only used it on next.js getInitialProps but I'm not even sure I should have done it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to receive a **callback**, You need to use callbackable-actions standardized actions.
`actions-creator` package has the callback capability, you can use to create callback-capability action objects.

```sh
npm install actions-creator
```

```js
import actionsCreator from "actions-creator"
const my_callback = () => {
    console.log("Hello, I am callback!!!")
}
const callbackable_action = actionsCreator.CALLBACKABLE.EXAMPLE(1, 2, 3, my_callback)
console.log(callbackable_action)
//      {
//          type: "CALLBACKABLE/EXAMPLE",
//          args: [1, 2, 3],
//          cb: f() my_callback,
//          _index: 1
//      }
callbackable_action.cb()
//      "Hello, I am callback!!!"
```

for more info, see: [Actions Creator](https://github.com/Ruben-Arushanyan/actions-creator)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the callback function as a parameter to your action, for example:

in your component you call your action:

```
yourFunction(data, callback())
```

and in your action:

```
yourFunction(data, callback){
  ... do what you have to ...
  callback()
}
```

Not a very clear example, but you should put your code in your question if you want t better answer.